# Intellij unable to run test in IDE - Junit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I can't run any of my test in Intellij, the file test is not recognized as one.

- In the modules settings Junit is checked
- junit is added in my `pom.xml`
- the `src/test/java` folder is added as Test Source folder

And the most awkward : I can run my test in the command line with `mvn test` and it works !

Here is a screenshot of my test file (to show that there is no run button and even a warning stating that my file is "not used")
[image]

Also I've seen some people recommending to use *Generate test* but when I use it I can't create a Junit Test: only Groovy and Spock appear :

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: Have you imported your pom into IDEA?

Comment: what do you mean @tgdavies ? intellij knows its a maven project and my pom.xml seems to work.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Press `Shift+Ctrl+A`, search for the `Add as Maven Project` and execute that action.
[image]

If that action isn't available, your project is already seen as a maven project.

Try if to reload maven projects will solve the problem.

Reloading is done via maven tool window. Click the reload all maven project button:
[image]